# How i get android api key for use in delphi xe5

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, sha1, delphi-xe5, api-key

i want to build android project with delphi xe5,i want to use google cloud messanging (gcm) for push notification, but i cant create google api key (sha1 fingerprint).. Anyone can help me?

Comment: No, i just try create api key at google, but i cant get sha1 fingerprint to get it. How i can get sha1? Is there a relation with delphi?

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the steps listed below to Create API key for GCM:

Go to:  http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

- Login with a Google account
- Click 'Create project'
- When you get to a page with a left side nav, make sure 'Services' is selected
- Turn 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android' ON
- Click on the 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android' link
- Click on the 'API access' link in the left navigation
- You should now be able to create a new server or browser key by clicking corresponding button

You may also use the Official Google Documentation for GCM as your reference in creating Cloud Messging: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: I cant get sha1 fingerprint to create api key